# Printing spaces based on the position of the character in Python

Tags: python

Your answers have helped me a lot before, but now I'm stuck on a problem that I can't find the answer to. I'm currently at the start of teaching myself Python, and I've come across an exercise I can't figure out. I need to print each of the characters of a string on a new line in reverse order, with the number of spaces before each character being equal to the character's position in the string. Ideally, this would use a for loop.

I can print each character on a new line and in reverse order fine, but my issue is that when I reverse the string, it reverses the position of each of the characters: e.g. in the string 'dog', 'd' is in position 1, but reversed, is in position 3. I'd like to print the number of spaces multiplied by the original position of the string, rather than after it has been reversed.

This is what I have so far (apologies for any dodgy code).

```
def print_reverse(text):
        x = 0
        spc = ' '
        for i in text[::-1]:
            print(spc * x, i)
            x += 1
```

print_reverse('dog')

```
Expected results:
  g
 o
d


Actual results:
g
 o
  d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is initially `x` is `0`. Instead you can try decreasing `x` from length of text:

```
def print_reverse(text):
    x = len(text)
    spc = ' '
    for i in text[::-1]:
        print(spc * x, i)
        x -= 1

print_reverse('dog')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the iteration, you iterate like `0,1,2,3,...`. You want decreasing spaces (`...3,2,1,0`), therefore try for example:

```
def print_reverse(text):
        x = 0
        spc = ' '
        for i in text[::-1]:
            print((len(text) - x)*spc,
            print(i)
            x += 1
```

Here you take the length of the string and substract your loop index. Same idea as the other stated solution by the user student, but slightly different implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_reverse(text):
    x = len(text)
    spc = ' '
    for i in text[::-1]:
        print(spc * x, i)
        x -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
def print_reverse(text):
        x = len(text)
        spc = ' '
        for i in text[::-1]:
            print(spc * x, i)
            x -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a couple lines with a little bit of generator comprehension and `enumerate`:

```
def print_reverse(text):
    for line in (' ' * (len(word)-i) + c for i, c in enumerate(text[::-1])):
        print(line)
```

`enumerate` returns each list item, as well as it's position in a list (or in this case a string).

So `enumerate('dog')` will return:

```
((0, 'd'), (1, 'o'), (2, 'g'))
```

If you subtract the position from the total length of the word (`len(word)-i`), you'll get the number of spaces you need in front of your leter.

This answer also uses a generator expression, which is easy way to apply the same expression for each item in a list.

Finally, `text[::-1]` gives you a reversed list (you could also do `reversed(text)`.